# LU factorization using Gaussian elimination

Tags: linear-algebra

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 1 & 2\\
4 & 6 & 3
\end{bmatrix}$

Gaussian elimination yields:
$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & | & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & | &-2 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & | &-8 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

How can I rewrite $A=LU$? I get that the left side of the elimination is $U$. However, I don't understand why the right side of the elimination is helpful to know. I checked, and it is not $L$. Why was this given in the problem. I can find $L=A*U^{-1}$. I am confused why the extra information was given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the left-hand side is equal to $X\cdot A$ for some matrix $X$, then the right-hand side is equal to $X \cdot I = X$. Essentially, it tracks the exact linear transformation performed on $A$ to get $U$.

To get $L$, we only need to take the inverse of $X$. This is easy for a matrix in lower triangular form.

Sure, you could take the inverse of $U$ and then multiply by $X$ to get $L$, but that takes more steps.

Triangular matrices make many calculations easier; that's why this kind of decomposition can be useful.